# Click href loads blank page

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to click this href to download a file and it does that just fine, but the click also triggers an page to load. The page is blank and then after the page load times out, it breaks the test.

```
cy.get(the href).click();
```

Is there a way to click the href without triggering the page load?

Comment: Please provide a code snippet of what you're referencing. We can only speculate what your problem is if we can't see it.

Comment: Does this also happen with a manual test? I guess what I am asking is if you click it with the mouse yourself does a page load or does this only happen in cypress?

Comment: @Maccurt No, the href doesn't load a new page it just downloads the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this to download the file and it is working:

```
cy.get("a")
  .should("have.attr", "href")
  .then(href => {
    cy.request(href).then(response => {
      if (response && response.body) {
        cy.writeFile("filePath", response.body);
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with javascript and links. Typically:

```
<a href="#" onclick="f()">hit me</a>
```

Clicking the link could do two things: load the current page (say `index.html`) with an empty anchor (`index.html#`), *and* execute the javascript, that does the download.

The solution would be to tell the browser not to follow the link.

```
function f() {
    ...
    return false;
}
```

But if the function takes long, the browser might preload the page.
What went wrong I do not know, and on testing your hands are tied.

Alternative:

```
<a href="javascript:f()">hit me</a>
```

I did not do JavaScript the last two years, so do not take only my word for these troubles. I hope someone else comes up with a more founded answer, and a better solution.